# How to export LibGDX game

Tags: linux, windows, macos, export, libgdx

What's the easiest way to export LibGDX game to Windows, Linux & OSX. So the user doesn't need to have Java installed? If the user must have Java installed, what is the best way to create simple 'one-click' launcher for the game?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is to use the tool *packr* which has been released just about two weeks ago. You can find it [here](https://github.com/libgdx/packr).

It will create an optimized (for libgdx) JVM and I think even creates an executable file. Optimized means that the JVM got stripped all not necessary parts and thus results in only a few MB extra.

Basically you'll need to create a `config.json` file with the following (example) content:

```
{
    "platform": "mac",
    "jdk": "/Users/badlogic/Downloads/openjdk-1.7.0-u45-unofficial-icedtea-2.4.3-macosx-x86_64-image.zip",
    "executable": "myapp",
    "appjar": "myapp.jar",
    "mainclass": "com/my/app/MainClass",
    "vmargs": [
       "-Xmx1G"
    ],
    "resources": [
        "pom.xml",
        "src/main/resources"
    ],
    "minimizejre": "soft",
    "outdir": "out-mac"
}
```

How to setup this config exactly can be read in the link I've posted on top. After that and after downloading packr, you can run it via `java -jar packr.jar config.json` from the commandline.

Comment: I've read something about it from the news page, but couldn't figure out, how it works. It seems too much complicated.

Comment: I've tried to add a small guide how to use it. It is really easy to use. You just need to read the page I've linked, all settings are described there.

Comment: I've tried that before, but just couldn't figure out, how to put resources in there, since they are already extracted in the jar.

Comment: And this config created 42kb file (out of 6mB jar) and obviously, it didn't work.
{
    "platform": "windows",
    "jdk": "openjdk-1.7.0-u45-unofficial-icedtea-2.4.3-windows-i586-image.zip",
    "executable": "MLibGDX",
    "appjar": "MLibGDX.jar",
    "mainclass": "cz/vilix/main/Desktop",
    "vmargs": [
       "-Xmx1G"
    ],
    "resources": [
    ],
    "minimizejre": "soft",
    "outdir": "out-mac"
}

Comment: I assume that you do not have everything in the same folder as the packr.jar? Probably it can't find neither the jdk zip, nor your .jar file to pack.

Comment: I do have. I've put everything (including the game jar, packr, jdk, config) to clean folder.

Comment: If you want, you could use eclipse, it has a built in function to do this on exporting.